# Where does Adobe Creative Suite professional save it's System Files?

Tags: windows-xp, adobe-creative-suite

I would like to know where Adobe Creative Suite Professional, when it's installed onto a Windows XP Computer, makes its system files.

Comment: Are you talking about the installed DLL's or temp files or registry settings? It might be more helpful to describe the problem and we can go at it that way.

Comment: Have you checked C:\Program Files - that's were most programs go

Comment: @DGivens I mean all files dll's exe temp registry etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Edit, Dynamic I Just brought it to my attention that you are talking about Adobe in general and not Acrobat. Simply remove the Acrobat part from all the paths below and you should be able to find the path you are looking for.

---

ehh... well...

(remove the (x86) part for 32 bit machies)

Main files -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 9.0
```

Some shared files mainly Acrobat -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat
```

Other general Adobe shared files -

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\
```

User specific settings

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Adobe
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\LocalLow\Adobe\Acrobat
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat
```

Registry is all over the place, but main path (user specific)

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat
```

Registry main path machine (x64)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat
```

Registry main path machine (x86)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat
```

Hopefully this helps. If you have something a bit more specific or say what you want to achieve, I may be able to help a lot better.

Comment: I think he meant the design suites

Comment: Oh bugger! I could swear that I read Acrobat! There's a few minutes I won't get back!

Comment: If I have only to remove the acrobat name the see all Adobe version, then I think that this answer is korrekt ;D